# Angular2 CLI rc0 failing on Travis CI and not local

Tags: javascript, angular, travis-ci, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 project build using Angular cli rc0 where the tests are running fine in local but failing in Travic CI due to the following constructor in node_modules.

```
/home/travis/build/evansmwendwa/blinky-angular/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:16
constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
```

Getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` in `fallbacks = []`.

Any idea how I can solve this since it's inside node_mdoules

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed for me by adding a global installation of angular cli as part of the travis build:

```
before_script:
  - npm install -g @angular/cli
```